# Decrease function in Kotlin

Tags: android, function, android-studio, kotlin

Hey, I have been trying to add decrease function in my android button counter app. There are three buttons(clear, increase, decrease) in my app. Increase is for increasing the counter, decrease is for decreasing the counter and clear is for clearing the textview. i am new here in android. So help me to write the code in kotlin

```
    button?.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            numTimeClicked += 1
            textview?.append("\n The button got tapped $numTimeClicked time")
            if (numTimeClicked != 1){
                textview?.append("s")
            }
        }
    })
    clear?.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (numTimeClicked <= 100){
                textview?.text = ""
            }

        }
    })
    Decrease?.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View){

            if (numTimeClicked >= 1  ){
             numTimeClicked -= 1
                textview?.append(numTimeClicked.toString())


            }
        }

    })

    }
private var userInput:EditText? = null
private  var button:Button? = null
private var textview:TextView?  = null
private var  clear:Button? = null
private var  Decrease:Button? = null
private var numTimeClicked = 0
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is the behaviour you're expecting and what happens in practice? We would gladly help, but without a bit more precision in the question it doesn't enable us to do so. Also, please fix the formatting, some braces don't match, and there are extra spaces in different places. You can use triple-backquotes to surround your code block (not triple single-quotes).

Comment: i have created  a simple button counter app with three buttons    button, clear, decrease. so  button displays the text in the textview  after pressing. and clear  makes the whole  textview clear both working perfectly but decrease button supposed to  remove  one row  after pressing the button but it's  not happening.

Comment: man, i am stuck  in this small app since yesterday, act fast please

Comment: Hey @KunalVerma, Can you please paste your xml file here as well? I will help you quickly then to fix your problem. Also please explain a bit more that what do you mean by removing one row after pressing the decrease button. If possible, please add some screenshots of your app to have more visibility of your usecase.

Comment: thanks, but i have solved the problem by applying some changes

Comment: Cool. Good to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

fun decreasenumber(var numTimeClicked : Int
) : Int{

numTimeClicked--

return  numTimeClicked

}

Comment: numTimeClicked: [ERROR : Type annotation was missing for parameter numTimeClicked

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line

```
textview?.append(numTimeClicked.toString())
```

to

```
textview?.text = "" + numTimeClicked
```

`append` behaves like this: 3 -> 32 -> 321, I think your purpose is to replace not append